# Rails active_model_serializer with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, pagination, active-model-serializers

I'm using active_model_serializer. Now I want to serialize an object with pagination, should I do the pagination logic in the controller or in the serializer?

If I choose to do the pagination in serializer, I need to pass the page_number and per_page to the serializer. How should I do that? My understanding is serializer only takes the model object.

Comment: Really unclear where serialization comes into this. What are you serializing? How does it relate to pagination? The two are *completely* separate, I can't imagine what one has to do with the other.

Comment: @meagar I'm trying to serialize the album, in which I want to do pagination for photos.

Comment: Are your trying to say that your result is an array and will_paginate is not working?

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis Sorry for the confusion. I'm actually using Kaminari and the pagination works well. My question is where to put the pagination logic - shall I put it in controller or shall I put it in serializer.

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers, AMS now includes pagination automatically when using either Kaminari or WP gems: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md

Comment: @rmcsharry FYI but Link Rot has set in.  I think this page is equivalent:

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Single Use Solution

Regular serializers are only concerned with single items - not paginated lists. The most straight forward way to add pagination is in the controller:

```
customers = Customer.page(params[:page])
respond_with customers, meta: {
  current_page: customers.current_page,
  next_page: customers.next_page,
  prev_page: customers.prev_page,
  total_pages: customers.total_pages,
  total_count: customers.total_count
}
```

## Reusable Solution

However, this is pretty tedious if you need pagination logic for multiple objects. Looking through the documentation for active_model_serializers you'll come across an `ArraySerializer` for serializing an array of objects. What I did was create `pagination_serializer.rb` using `ArraySerializer` to automatically add the meta tag for paginated arrays:

```
# my_app/app/serializers/pagination_serializer.rb
class PaginationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer
  def initialize(object, options={})
    meta_key = options[:meta_key] || :meta
    options[meta_key] ||= {}
    options[meta_key][:pagination] = {
      current_page: object.current_page,
      next_page: object.next_page,
      prev_page: object.prev_page,
      total_pages: object.total_pages,
      total_count: object.total_count
    }
    super(object, options)
  end
end
```

Once you have `PaginationSerializer` added to your rails app, you simple need to call it when you need pagination meta tags from your controller:

```
customers = Customer.page(params[:page])
respond_with customers, serializer: PaginationSerializer
```

Note: I wrote this to use [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) as the paginator. However, it can easily be modified to work with any pagination gem or custom solution.

Comment: This is a pretty tedious and repetitive way to go about it if you have lots of resources that you want to paginate.

Comment: @MarkMurphy You are right - very tedious. I'm in the process of moving the pagination details into a serializer of its own and will update my answer as soon as I work out the remaining bugs. Until then you can lookup `ArraySerializer`

Comment: @MarkMurphy I updated my answer to show how to use ArraySerializer to clean up the code and be more DRY

Comment: I wanted the pagination keys to be top level so I also overwrote #as_json on ``PagedSerializer < ActiveModel::ArraySerializer``



     def as_json(*args) 
        @options[:hash] = hash = {} 
        @options[:unique_values] = {} 

        hash.merge!(@options[:pagination]) if @options.key?(:pagination) 

        root = @options[:root] 
        if root.present? 
          hash.merge!(root => serializable_array) 
          include_meta(hash) 
          hash  
        else  
          serializable_array  
        end  
      end

Comment: Thanks for providing such good solution, but it seems that `ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer` should be `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer`.

Comment: @LiDong it depends on what version of `active_model_serializers` you have. 0.10.0 and newer requires `ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer` - older versions require `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer`

Comment: @lightswitch05 Yes, you are right, I am using 0.9.3.

Comment: Great solution but no longer required, see: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md

Comment: How to add pagination links document changed URL to https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md

Comment: As of version 0.10 this strategy won't work anymore due to meta options being moved to the adapter (ie meta isn't handled by CollectionSerializer). So, a similar approach can be used by creating an adapter (for example the JsonApi adapter provided by the library does links automatically if your resource supports them)

Answer (score 6):

2020 update: active_model_serializer now supports this out of the box if you use `json_api` schema, but the docs also teach you how to add it if you use the `json` schema.

The docs are here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/howto/add_pagination_links.md

Below I explain how to achieve the desired results if you are using the `json_api` or the `json` adapters. Check which one you're using on `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter`.

#### If you are using the JSON API adapter (your ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api)

Pagination links will be included in your response automatically as long as
the resource is paginated and if you are using the `JsonApi` adapter.

If you want pagination links in your response, use [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)
or [WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

Kaminari examples

```rb
#array
@posts = Kaminari.paginate_array([1, 2, 3]).page(3).per(1)
render json: @posts

#active_record
@posts = Post.page(3).per(1)
render json: @posts
```

WillPaginate examples

```rb
#array
@posts = [1,2,3].paginate(page: 3, per_page: 1)
render json: @posts

#active_record
@posts = Post.page(3).per_page(1)
render json: @posts
```

```rb
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

ex:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "articles",
      "id": "3",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
        "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
        "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
        "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=3&page[size]=1",
    "first": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=1&page[size]=1",
    "prev": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=2&page[size]=1",
    "next": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=4&page[size]=1",
    "last": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=13&page[size]=1"
  }
}
```

ActiveModelSerializers pagination relies on a paginated collection with the methods `current_page`, `total_pages`, and `size`, such as are supported by both [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

#### If you are using the JSON adapter (your ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json)

If you are not using `JSON` adapter, pagination links will not be included automatically, but it is possible to do so using `meta` key.

Add this method to your base API controller.

```rb
def pagination_dict(collection)
  {
    current_page: collection.current_page,
    next_page: collection.next_page,
    prev_page: collection.prev_page, # use collection.previous_page when using will_paginate
    total_pages: collection.total_pages,
    total_count: collection.total_count
  }
end
```

Then, use it on your render method.

```rb
render json: posts, meta: pagination_dict(posts)
```

ex.

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever."
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "current_page": 3,
    "next_page": 4,
    "prev_page": 2,
    "total_pages": 10,
    "total_count": 10
  }
}
```

You can also achieve the same result if you have a helper method that adds the pagination info in the meta tag. For instance, in your action specify a custom serializer.

```rb
render json: @posts, each_serializer: PostPreviewSerializer, meta: meta_attributes(@posts)
```

```rb
#expects pagination!
def meta_attributes(collection, extra_meta = {})
  {
    current_page: collection.current_page,
    next_page: collection.next_page,
    prev_page: collection.prev_page, # use collection.previous_page when using will_paginate
    total_pages: collection.total_pages,
    total_count: collection.total_count
  }.merge(extra_meta)
end
```

#### Attributes adapter

This adapter does not allow us to use `meta` key, due to that it is not possible to add pagination links.

Comment: The key here is `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api` in a file in your config/intializers/ams.rb.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/x1wins/tutorial-rails-rest-api/blob/master/lib/pagination.rb

```
# /lib/pagination.rb
class Pagination
  def self.build_json object, param_page = {}
    ob_name = object.name.downcase.pluralize
    json = Hash.new
    json[ob_name] = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(object.to_a, param_page: param_page)
    json[:pagination] = {
        current_page: object.current_page,
        next_page: object.next_page,
        prev_page: object.prev_page,
        total_pages: object.total_pages,
        total_count: object.total_count
    }
    return json
  end
end
```

how to use

```
#app/controller/posts_controller.rb
#post#index
render json: Pagination.build_json(@posts)
```

full source https://github.com/x1wins/tutorial-rails-rest-api